# AR transaction not working as expected. First record saves, second doesn't, but first record isn't being destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to use AR transactions to make sure both records, or neither are created. I have a Photo model, and a Post model that takes a photo. I want to either create both, or neither. My code looks like this:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :photo, :body, presence: true

  def self.create_from_upload(photo: nil, body: nil)
    self.transaction do
      photo = Photo.create(photo: photo)
      post = Post.create(photo: photo, body: body)
    end
    post
  end
end
```

Here, the photo is the uploaded file from the form, and the body is a string. If a photo is passed in, but not a body string, the Photo is being created, but the Post isn't, but the Photo is not being destroyed by the transaction

Why isn't the transaction deleting the Photo record?

Answer (score 0):

`create` doesn't raise an exception. That means the `transaction` block completes normally, and thus commits its changes (excluding those that the second `create` has internally given up on -- but those don't abort the surrounding transaction).

The simplest way to make this do what you expect would be to use `create!`, which will raise if it fails to create & persist the record.

Alternatively, you can check the objects' states after the `create` at the end of the `transaction` block and explicitly raise an exception there.

Comment: Cool, I just tried this, and it deletes the Photo as expected, however because an exception is raised, I don't have access to the model in order to display errors to the user, like `post.errors.full_messages`. Is there a way to do this, or would it be better to just manually check if `post.persisted?`, and if not, then manually delete the Photo, rather than using a transaction?

Comment: That's the "alternatively" case: you need `transaction` to see an exception, but it's fine to then rescue it in the surrounding method. As a special case, if you raise `ActiveRecord::Rollback`, then `transaction` will automatically rescue it for you.